# Exploding a string results in weird array

Tags: php, string, explode

I have a string that looks like this `"thing aaaa"` and I'm using `explode()` to split the string into an array containing all the words that are separated by space. I execute something like this `explode (" ", $string)` .

I'm not sure why but the result is : `["thing","","","","aaaa"]`; Does anyone have an idea why I get the three empty arrays in there ?

**EDIT :** This is the function that I'm using that in :

```
public function query_databases() {

        $arguments_count = func_num_args();
        $status = [];
        $results = [];
        $split =[];

        if ($arguments_count > 0) {

            $arguments = func_get_args();

            $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($arguments));

            foreach ($iterator as $key => $value) {
                array_push($results, trim($value));
            }
            unset($value);

            $filtered = $this->array_unique_values($results, "String");

            foreach ($filtered as $key => $string) {

                if (preg_match('/\s/',$string)) {
                    array_push($split, preg_split("/\s/", $string));
                } else {
                    array_push($split, $string);
                }

            }
            unset($string);

            echo "Terms : ".json_encode($split)."<br>";

            foreach ($filtered as $database) {

                echo "Terms : ".json_encode()."<br>";
                $_action = $this->get_database($database);
                echo "Action : ".json_encode($_action)."<br>";
            }
            unset($database);


        } else {
            return "[ Databases | Query Databases [ Missing Arguments ] ]";
        }

    }
```

It might be something else that messes up the result ?!

Comment: Most browsers ignore whitespace unless `&nbsp;` was used -- What is the content of your string? Use `var_dump()`.

Comment: Must be something *funny* with the input string as it works for me -> http://codepad.org/pXoZ3EW0

Comment: can we see the entire code? how youre storing it, echoing it, etc

Comment: Seems there are some invisible characters (or even more whitespace) between your words.  http://codepad.org/g46oM0hd

Comment: Are you sure the string only has a single space between the words? The result you report is what I'd expect with 4 spaces between the words.

Comment: @Barmar ~ I `trim()` before, so it shouldn't right ?

Comment: No, `trim()` only removes spaces at the ends, not the middle.

Comment: I see, so I'll have to use something else to trim all the whitespace but the one space between words :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Barmar said, my `trim()` just removes all the space before and after the words, so that is why I had more values in the array than I should have had.

I found that this little snippet : `preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', $value )` ; replacing my `trim()` would fix it :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to create an array by spaces, you might want to consider preg_split:

```
preg_split("/\s+/","thing aaaa");
```

which gives you array ("thing","aaaa");

[Taken from here.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php#37467)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$str = str_replace(" ", ",", $string);
explode(",",$str);
```

This way you can see if it is just the whitespace giving you the problem if you output 4 commas, it's because you have 4 whitespaces.